# ledermann/rails-settings gem doesn't work with RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Version 2.5.0 doesn't work with RailsAdmin. It fails as soon as you try viewing any model that uses has_settings.

Returned error and stacktrace:

Error: `undefined method` constantize' for nil:NilClass`

Stacktrace:

```
ledermann-rails-settings (2.5.0) lib/rails-settings/setting_object.rb:78:in `_target_class'
ledermann-rails-settings (2.5.0) lib/rails-settings/setting_object.rb:82:in `_setting?'
ledermann-rails-settings (2.5.0) lib/rails-settings/setting_object.rb:28:in `respond_to?'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Model>'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:66:in `each'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:66:in `detect'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:66:in `block in <class:Model>'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:77:in `instance_eval'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:77:in `block in register_instance_option'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/lazy_model.rb:66:in `method_missing'
rails_admin (3.1.2) app/helpers/rails_admin/application_helper.rb:74:in `wording_for'
rails_admin (3.1.2) app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:36:in `action_missing'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:229:in `_handle_action_missing'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.0.6) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.0.6) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
searchkick (5.2.4) lib/searchkick/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.0.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
actionview (7.0.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
railties (7.0.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
railties (7.0.6) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `public_send'
railties (7.0.6) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `method_missing'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
```